# how to use setMyLocationEnabled(true) and addMarker in google maps v2?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I try to use `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` but need the permission and I already add it but it still not working. also the marker too. I try to write the code in **MainActivity.java** but it still doesn't working.

**This is my MapsActivity.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LatLng latLngBiru = new LatLng(35.6829733, 139.7321275);
    private LatLng latLngKuning = new LatLng(35.6847009, 139.7314891);
    private LatLng latLngMerah = new LatLng(35.6839537, 139.7308615);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLngBiru)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                .title("tempat rahasia").snippet("rahasia lho"));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLngKuning)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW))
                .title("bangunan kampus").snippet("bangunan utama"));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLngMerah)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                .title("kantin kampus").snippet("makan makan"));

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.21462, 106.84513)).title("Hello Maps ");
        mMap.addMarker(marker);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(-6.21462, 106.84513)).zoom(12).build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }


    }
}
```

**This is my activity_maps.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context="com.mqa.android.ewasapp.MapsActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**This is my activity_main.xml**

here where google maps shows

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <FrameLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.mqa.android.ewasapp.MapsActivity" />

</FrameLayout>
```

please help me at least to setMyLocationEnable. thank you before.

Answer (score 0):

to request the permissions use use the location

```
private boolean mayRequestLocation(){

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            1);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
            1);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return true;
    }

        return false;
}
```

Comment: where setMyLocationEnable(true) should I put?

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama the setMyLocationEnable is only to appear in the map a button to focus on the location

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama the error is because of the permitions?

Comment: it don't have any error but it cant show the MyLocation button on top right

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama but the application have the permissions to access the location?